# JSON.stringify() not escaping apostrophe

Tags: json

...using JSON2.js and JQUERY

as you can see from the first image the object property **customerReport.Title** has an apostrophe. In the code you can see that I'm calling JSON.stringify() into **reportAsJson** string which still has the unescaped apostrophe.

the error returned by $.ajax() is `{"Message":"Invalid object passed in, \u0027:\u0027 or \u0027}\u0027 expected. ...`

Initially I'm just going to ban apostrophe's from the user, but I thought JSON.stringify() handled this or do I need to set some option????

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape single quotes in JSON. Where does that `{"Message":"Invalid object passed in...` come from?

Comment: What is returning this error message?

Comment: @MattBall i copied that from firebug's console panel from the Response tab

Comment: see updated screenshot for source of error.  My .net code never gets called, unless I remove the apostorphe

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid removing these *apostrophes* replacing them with an HTML entity `&#39;` - *that's a single quot* - and later decode HTML entities either in the client or server-side.

Comment: trying to avoid just that.. if I can

Answer (score 1):

Following has worked for me after so many failed tries for stringify and other JSON parsing functions:

```
updatedString = string.replace(/('[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\s*)'(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+')/g,"$1\\\'$2");
```

where

- string = string having apostrophe in it.
- updatedString = string with apostrophe issue resolved/escaped